# CRON @reboot vncserver?

Tags: cron, vnc, tightvncserver, mta

Is there any reason per-user cronjobs running vncserver `@reboot` wouldn't run?

When I reboot the machine and look into `/var/log/syslog`, I see the jobs being run, then cron saying `(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)`.

I'd rather not configure postfix just to figure out why these jobs aren't running, but I'm not sure I have another choice here. Unless the program mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82093/minimal-mta-that-delivers-mail-locally-for-cron) will yield me the email data.

EDIT:

Well, I installed femtomail per its readme, but got this from cron: `MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x0001, #012)`.

One byte? That hardly seems like it could be an error code.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to run `vncserver` as a specific user:

```bsh
@reboot sudo -u YOUR_USERNAME vncserver :1 -localhost -geometry 1920x1080
```

If the above doesn't solve the problem, make `cron` start `vncserver` every minute (to get the error as fast as possible) and redirect the stdout and stderr logs to a file, which will tell you the actual error.

```bsh
* * * * * vncserver :1 -localhost -geometry 1920x1080 >> ~/cron_vncserver_output.log 2>&1
```